# Why do IE and Firefox render the same image differently, how can I prevent it?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, image, rendering

[image]

On the left you will notice the google logo rendered by IE, I drew a black line at the top and bottom of the G which extends into the FF windows which rendered the same exact logo yet the FF version renders the image larger. There is NO css linked to this page, just plain and simple Html.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and can I prevent it? Is my box just fubar and no one else gets this behavior?

Edit: Failed to mention IE7/FF3

Edit: Posted Html as requested

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="ctl00_Head1"><title></title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just created a composite image of screenshots of the Google image in IE, Firefox & Chrome and they're all in perfect register (top 2 images at 30% opacity).

I believe it has to be a custom zoom you've got set in one of your browsers. Check IE's zoom at the right of the status bar, for example.

[image: composite image]
<sub>(source: [mikescommunity.com](http://mikescommunity.com/public/images/googleimagecomposite.png))</sub>

Comment: It turns out to be an issue with FF3 and a bug in either the server 2008 x64 build or the zoom plugin. Tried several combos with varying results but bottom line life is better now. Thanks.

Comment: Which zoom plugin? I'm curious which it is, FF3 or the plugin. Have you tried uninstalling the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Is text rendering any different? Might be that you have zoomed the page in FF (or IE)?

Can try Ctrl-0 to reset zoom sizing (works in both), I have a logitech mouse with a free spinning wheel, so this happens to me quite a bit when I forget the scroll wheel is still spinning and hit the Ctrl key. Plenty other places where the zoom etc could be set.

Could also be something entirely different, but generally I find that IE and FF render images much the same.

Wouldn't call the box fubar based on that, more likely a software setting somewhere... but hey, it's nearly Christmas, and if you want an excuse for a new box, I won't tell anyone :)